# 1950s film about a small black box which teleports him to other worlds

Tags: story-identification, movie

I'm looking for the name of a black and white 1950's science fiction movie. It starts out with a man that finds a small black box with a little cone on one side at a construction dig site. A little boy, I think his son, asks to keep the box. He takes this box home and somehow drops it and it shatters into pieces. He goes to sleep with a piece of the object in his hand and next thing we know he teleports to a different world. He convinces someone in his family about this experience and takes them to this other world and they find many of these black boxes. They find a dead humanoid with a headgear that has a wire which is connected to one of these boxes. They put the head gear on and find out information that is contained in the box. The information they learn is about two different planets which are at war.

They then are able to teleport from planet to planet when they stand on a round platform. I thought it was called the Terminots or something like that.

Comment: see also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53141/looking-for-novel-from-50s-or-60s (about the novel on which the film is based)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a 1960's movie name "[The Terrornauts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terrornauts)" which looks like it matches some of your description, but I've not seen it and am mainly going by the similarity in the names.

Parts of the Wikipedia plot summary:

> .... Dr. Burke tells of his father's discovery at an archaeological dig in France of a cube that gave him strange dreams as a boy, inspiring him to become an astronomer. The signal is sent and reaches the asteroid. The asteroid has on it a huge installation that receives the radio signal and answers it with a spaceship sent riding down the radio beam to the point of transmission. When the spacecraft arrives at Project Star Talk, it picks up the transmitter shed and carries it, the project staff and the 2 witnesses to the alien installation.

....

> Upon arrival at the asteroid, the team is greeted by a robot that takes them through a series of tests. After each test, they are provided with rewards such as food for the intelligence test, a weapon for the motivation test and a "Knowledge Cube" for the knowledge test. After a tour of a control room, they are then brought to a chamber with a small platform and a figure in a chair, who simply happens to be the long dead caretaker of the base. As they head back to the control room, Ben bumps Sandy onto the platform and she is "transposed" in a puff of smoke to a distant planet peopled by savages who try to kill her. Dr. Burke then follows Sandy to the planet armed with the gun and effects a rescue before she is killed discovering the secret of the Knowledge Cubes in the process. Dr. Burke plugs in to the cube, and the horrible secret is revealed, the planet of savages is the home of the survivors of an interstellar war that is fast approaching Earth, and the Star Talk team are the only ones who can use the advanced weapons of the installation to stop an invading enemy fleet from destroying Planet Earth....

Comment: My two favorite things about this film - the Dalek-like robots that trundle about the space station, and the appearance of Carry on alum Charles Hawtrey