# looking for novel from 50's or 60's

Tags: story-identification, novel, spaceship

I am looking for novel from 50's or 60's.The book is about a "dream" which he is shown how to wind a coil. He winds it and almost goes through the wall. He later builds a spaceship out of concrete and uses the coils for drive.
if i remember he was a owner of some construction company..
thats it there is no more..    please help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're likely thinking of ["The Wailing Asteroid"](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1220489.The_Wailing_Asteroid#) (1960) by Murray Leinster. A favorite of mine as a kid, only last year did I find the movie based on it: ["The Terrornauts"](http://youtu.be/0GzDgBXgfvE) (1967) (adaptation by John Brunner)

[image]

> Now, very reflectively, he plugged in a metal lathe and carefully turned out a
>    very tiny specimen of the peculiarly-shaped magnetic core. He wound it by hand,
>    very painstakingly. It was a tricky job. It was six o'clock Saturday morning
>    when the specimen was finished. He connected the leads to a storage battery and
>    threw the switch. The small object tore itself to bits, and the core landed
>    fifteen feet from where it had been. Burke beamed.

Comment: I have to find a copy of this now!! I loved and it more than 40 years ago..and It stuck with me.. I have been looking with google for about a year! Thank you again