# Movie I saw in late 70s where humans found a dead civilization with little black boxes that could teach them anything

Tags: story-identification, movie

It was a late-night movie I saw late 70s sometime. It was in color I think.

Humans somehow ended up on a planet that a previous civilization had occupied. The civilization left behind all kinds of cool stuff but the thing I remember most were stacks of little black boxes. And if you put on a little cap and connected it to a particular box you could learn whatever information was stored in that box. There were language boxes, engineering boxes... all kinds of stuff. I though that was pretty cool.

Comment: See also https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/53141/looking-for-novel-from-50s-or-60s (about the novel on which the film is based)

Comment: By the way, if you're interested in the concept of "instant learning" *per se*, then I heartily recommend Asimov's novella *Profession*. You can find the full text link here: http://employees.oneonta.edu/blechmjb/JBpages/m360/Profession%20I%20Asimov.pdf

Comment: An interesting short story with a related concept is [Environment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/159872).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The black instruction boxes appear in Murray Leinster's *The Wailing Asteroid* (1960). In the book you can also access some of their contents by sleeping near one, so that you dream the contents, but later in the book a "browsing cap" appears.

Also, in the book the humans do find themselves on a planet left by a previous civilization.

> which was actually *their* civilization. Humans turn out to be descendants of a prehistoric garrison manning the M-387 asteroid, whence they escaped on Earth when they found themselves stranded in the Solar System and food began to run low. They brought some entertainment boxes with them, and the pieces of one of them is what sets the 'hero' on the road that leads him to land on the asteroid.

So I think you might have seen [*The Terrornauts* (1967)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Terrornauts) which was based on that book. [Here](https://youtu.be/TRjqZGiulhw?t=69) you see the sequence with the caps and box:

[image]

Comment: Yeeeeees that was it, "The Terrornauts". Thank you! As soon as I saw this screen cap I knew it was it. I had forgotten all about the flying city fortress thing. [The Space Station/Fortress](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rS8v.jpg)